# Jersey client: LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to cast bundle resource

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I have two Eclipse plug-ins that I build to interface with two different REST services using the Jersey http client. Right now I am getting the error that appears in the title after opening both views - one uses on plug-in and the other uses the second plug-in. The first one opened works fine and the second one opened gets the error.

I believe this is an OSGi resource issue but I am not sure of the best way to resolve the problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!